# How to using typescript with openfaas handler?

Tags: node.js, openfaas

I'm using openfaas for the first time. I followed by [this guide](https://docs.openfaas.com/tutorials/cli-with-node/).

The cli creates `handler.js` file.

Is it possible to working with typescript? creates typescript file instead of javascript file?